# \hrulefill and \dotfill

Tags: latex3, xparse

The LaTeX2e sources defines `\dotfill` and `\hrulefill` as follows:

[image]

Interestingly, I noticed that in the `multicolrule` package, the author makes use of TeX primitives defined in L3 syntax as follows:

[image]

Of course, this caught my attention, and I found several similar TeX primitives like `\mode_leave_vertical:`, `\tex_leaders:D`, `\tex_hrule:D`, `\tex_hfill:D`, etc. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the `\hrulefill` nor `\dotfill` defined in the `sources3.pdf` nor `interface3.pdf`.

How can these well-defined commands, `\hrulefill` nor `\dotfill`, be rewritten using L3 syntax? I am asking just in the scope of learning.

Comment: this use of primitives (the command with `:D`) is not recommended, see 5.2 Access to primitives in l3styleguide.pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The author of the package did mention it. Was just curious.

Comment: An interface for `\leaders` is not currently available.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the update. Maybe we should close the question or combine Ulrike's and your comment as an answer.